# i try to change the color of the background by using the current time

Tags: javascript, web, background

i try to run my code but it does not work

i already tried to use a "color" variable,using rgb(x,x,x) codes,#xxxx,without quotation marks...

```
var thehours = new Date().getHours();
if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 12) {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
} else if (thehours >= 12 && thehours < 18) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
} else if (thehours >= 18 && thehours < 24) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";  
}
```

in console i get this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at design.js:3"

Comment: it is working inside a html page ...

Comment: Where are you calling this function? Seems like it's being executed before body is defined. Perhaps you're calling it inside your `head` without waiting for DOM to load?

Answer (score 0):

Is your script in your `<head>` tag? If so, try adding `defer` to your `<script>` tag.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="design.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: no,my script is on a file named "design.js",and this is my head: <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ntegrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="desig.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="design.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Html docs are parsed/loaded top to bottom and each time the parser encounters a `script` tag, it will pause parsing and execute the script immediately. Because the body tag has not yet been parsed when the script executes, `document.body` is not defined (i.e. it is `undefined`). `defer` tells the parser to finish parsing the entire html document and THEN execute the script. Because your script has the defer tag, it now executes once the `body` has been defined and so it works as expected. Hope that helps understand!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure that the `document.body` element is defined before running your script (for example, the `body` won't be defined if you run the script in the `<head>` of your `<html>` document)

One way to ensure that `document.body` is defined would be to wrap your script in a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler on the `document` object as shown below:

```js
/* Set up the DOMContentLoaded event handler on the document to ensure
your script is only run once the document.body is defined */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  /* This script only runs once the whole page's "load" event fires 
  which means that the body element will be defined */
  var thehours = new Date().getHours();
  if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 12) {
    /* Modified for this demo */
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
  } else if (thehours >= 12 && thehours < 18) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  } else if (thehours >= 18 && thehours < 24) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }    

});
```

See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) more information on the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but is probably being called in the wrong place, it should be called after the page has loaded, I would recommend putting it in a  tag at the end of your body, or you can use a button and put it in a function